# What would happen to a wizard after their death, whose soul is fragmented, but who didn't create Horcruxes?

Tags: harry-potter

In the *Harry Potter* franchise, someone's soul is fragmented if they commit cold-blooded murder without remorse. Tom Riddle didn't create Horcruxes immediately when murdering Myrtle or the Gaunts, but those murders fragmented his soul and allowed him to create the diary and the ring Horcruxes *a few months later*, that is, he put a fragment of his soul into each item months after the murders (after asking Slughorn about creating multiple Horcruxes).

We know that

> after Tom Riddle's death, his main self is stuck in limbo in the baby-sized form we see in *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows – Part 2*.

But what happens to a wizard who split their soul by commiting cold-blooded murder, but with all the fragments inside their body? Perhaps this is a broader question on what happens in the afterlife to someone evil in the *Harry Potter* universe.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/50997/4918 What happens to UnHorcruxed Soul Fragments?